# OpenCart: Create custom controller class

Tags: php, html, opencart

I have a custom script which is meant to generate images for the customer.

I NEED this script to be part of controller, because I need the script to be able to use:

```
if (!$this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('account/download', '', true);

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', true));
    }
```

In order to check if the customer is logged in. Otherwise, anyone can access this link even when logged out, which is very dangerous for my shop.

In my custom script, I have included:

```
<?php
require_once('system/engine/controller.php');
class ControllerTestAbc extends Controller{
     public function index()
     {
          echo 'Hello World';
          exit;
     }
}
?>
```

I'm just echoing hello world to see if the page would run. However, the page is just blank.

NOTE: I am attempting to access this script using href like:

```
$viewimg ="<a target='_blank' href='view_code.php?id=".$id."&showDate=".$showDate." 'class='cat_links'>".$showName."<font size='-1'></a>";
```

Why is the page blank? I've included the path to the controller engine, however the function index() doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the page blank?

You're getting a 500 error. Check your log file.

If you don't know where PHP is logging add: `phpinfo();exit;` at the top of your script temporarily and it will show you which error log is in use.

Alternatively, you could try temporarily turning on logging to the screen with:
`ini_set('display_errors',1);error_reporting E_ALL;`

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your custom script inside `controller` directory.

Lets say your script is `catalog/controller/account/view_code.php`, you need to name the class as <strike>`ControllerViewCode`</strike> `ControllerAccountViewCode`.

EDIT: I was wrong. Class name should be `ControllerAccountViewCode` as stated by @Abdullah-Al-Shakib in comment, not `ControllerViewCode`.

Comment: I did that and it still doesn't work. 

When I take the exact url address of the route, route=account/view_code.php and put it on the browser, the page loads okay, but if I use href, it doesn't work

Comment: @bogalakon you are worng, class name would be ControllerAccountViewCode

Comment: The code still doesn't work. It still can't find the class controller.

However, if I put the route directly on the browser, the page works fine. But if I use href to create a link to that page, it can't find the class

Comment: @arsenalftw067 You can't access the custom script directly, you need to go to `index.php?route=account/view_code` to run it.